# Windows Hello - detect face change

Tags: sdk, uwp, face, windows-hello

User setups `Windows Hello`. `UWP`-application can authorize user.

Now user changed face in `system settings`. How can app detect that after it was started using `UWP` `SDK`?

Comment: Did you mean that if the user changed face in windows settings, then, if the user switched back to the app, you want to force the user to login again?

Comment: I haven't tried this feature out. But from reading docs I think in this scenario it is up to the app to decide when to re-authenticate the user. That is, the app won't get a notification of user updating face in system settings.

Comment: Yes. Face change event is for asking user to authenticate by login and password.

Comment: You could use `Window.Current.Activated` event and app's `App_Resuming` event to handle this scenario when the user switch back to the app.

Comment: What should be changed after settings update? And what if the app is not working now? In ‘Android’ there is a key, which will be invalidated. In ‘iOS’ there’s a array of bytes, which you can save and check each time you want to detect fingers list changes

Comment: Maybe, the private-public key would be updated. You could validate it in your login code block.